# bootstrap dropdown not working on iOS

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu, web, twitter-bootstrap

For a clients website I made a Bootstrap menu with dropdown. Everything seems to be working fine in Safari, Firefox, etc. But when I try to view the dropdown items on iPhone/iPad, it's not working. Does somebody understand why?

Here's the (website stripped down to only the menu) link to the menu: http://www.buzz-creative.nl/_klanten/menutest

Thanks in advance!

Melissa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if your links do not have an href to follow you still need to provide something for them to work, so just plug something like `href="#"` into your dropdown links to signify that they are actually links.

Comment: Thanks so much Andres! I never thought of that because it was working fine on my 'normal' browsers... great, that fixed the problem!

Comment: @Meltdown87 awesome :) felt it had to be that. If the answer satisfied your question please mark it as such to close this thread.

Comment: Uhh new here... how do i do that :P ?

Comment: You can tick that grey checkmark right next to the answer to signal approval.